# Does android keep a log of when it starts?

Tags: android, logging, boot, safe-mode, parental-control

I'm making a parental control/accountability app for android.  It consists of a monitoring service that runs in the background and starts when the phone is booted.

Unfortunately, I have found that when android is started in "Safe Mode", services are not started automatically, and because of this my app has a serious flaw.

While in safe mode, the web and other apps can be started without my monitoring service running.

I thought that if it isn't possible to monitor app activity while in safe mode, maybe I could at least have my app detect if the phone was previously in safe mode.  Then it could maybe alert the parent or accountability partner?

Does Android keep any log of this?  Or any boot log in general?